# Issue using Encrypted password in connection string for Teradatasql python module with fastload

Tags: python, module, teradata

Get error Unable to parse JSON connection parameters, Caused by invalid character 'C' in string escape code, when using encrypted password

Updated to the newest version of TeradataSQL (16.20.0.48) to get fastload support.  My password is encrypted using stored password protection, and works with other teradata sql commands.  When using the '{fn teradata_try_fastload}' function for the fastload, I will get the connection error.  When I replace the password with the actual password, the code will work.

Variable

```py
userID = 'userID'
userPWD3 = 'password' #works with everything
userPWD = r'ENCRYPTED_PASSWORD(file:\\Path\JTErc\PassKey.properties,file:\\Path\JTErc\EncPass.properties)' #works with the CREATE and DROP tables, but not fastload
```

Connection String

```py
con = teradatasql.connect (host = 'host',user=userID,password=userPWD3)
```

Fastload

```py
with con.cursor() as cur:
    sRequest = "{fn teradata_nativesql}{fn teradata_autocommit_off}"
    print (sRequest)
    cur.execute (sRequest)

    aaoValues = [[1,None,],]

    sInsert = "{fn teradata_try_fastload}INSERT INTO " + sTableName + "(?, ?)"
    print (sInsert)
    cur.execute (sInsert, aaoValues)
```

getting the following error:

```
File "AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\teradatasql\__init__.py", line 770, in executemany
    raise OperationalError (sErr)

OperationalError: Unable to parse JSON connection parameters
 at gosqldriver/teradatasql.ParseConParams ConParams.go:59
 at gosqldriver/teradatasql.(*teradataFastLoadManager).connectFastLoad TeradataFastLoadManager.go:548
 at gosqldriver/teradatasql.(*teradataFastLoadManager).executeInsert TeradataFastLoadManager.go:1170
 at gosqldriver/teradatasql.newTeradataRows TeradataRows.go:287
 at gosqldriver/teradatasql.(*teradataStatement).QueryContext TeradataStatement.go:122
 at gosqldriver/teradatasql.(*teradataConnection).QueryContext TeradataConnection.go:2021
 at database/sql.ctxDriverQuery ctxutil.go:48
 at database/sql.(*DB).queryDC.func1 sql.go:1464
 at database/sql.withLock sql.go:3032
 at database/sql.(*DB).queryDC sql.go:1459
 at database/sql.(*Conn).QueryContext sql.go:1701
 at main.goCreateRows goside.go:598
 at main._cgoexpwrap_e6e101e164fa_goCreateRows _cgo_gotypes.go:331
 at runtime.call64 asm_amd64.s:574
 at runtime.cgocallbackg1 cgocall.go:316
 at runtime.cgocallbackg cgocall.go:194
 at runtime.cgocallback_gofunc asm_amd64.s:826
 at runtime.goexit asm_amd64.s:2361
Caused by invalid character 'C' in string escape code
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem corresponds to GOSQL-45 FastLoad interop with Stored Password Protection.
It has been fixed in teradatasql 16.20.0.49 which is now available from pypi.